# Threshold ROC vs. Cut-Off in confusion matrix (binary regression)

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, roc, confusion-matrix

I am trying to understand the link between the threshold in ROC-analysis and the threshold defined in classification table. Criterion is binary with 0 or 1.

> 1) Someone can determine a confusion table for a binary classification
>   task:
>
> ```
> threshold=0.5
> predicted_values<-ifelse(predict(model,type="response")>threshold,1,0)
> actual_values<-df$Criterion
> conf_matrix<-table(predicted_values,actual_values)
> conf_matrix
> ```
>
> Threshold-value can range between 0 and 1 here. Above 1, it causes
>   errors / implausible values.
>
> 2) Someone can compute a ROC-analysis and determine an optimal cut-off
>   value like shown in the answer below in this posting:
>   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868036/specificity-sensitivity-vs-cut-off-points-using-proc-package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ecF.png)
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ecF.png):
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868036/specificity-sensitivity-vs-cut-off-points-using-proc-package
>
> **Question:**
>
> The obtained threshold in ROC-analysis can exceed one (or is even
>   larger, see example linked). Thus, it cannot be used as threshold in
>   confusion table.
>
> Can someone tell explain me: why are those values not fitting to each
>   other?

**Edit/ Addition:**

Thanks to feedback! Below I am posting my code and kindly ask for some feedback about plausibility / interpretation of threshold of 1.347756.

**Data:**

```
structure(list(predictor1 = c(0.6875, 0.666666666666667, 0.9375, 
0.6875, 0.625, 0.75, 0.5, 0.625, 0.666666666666667, 0.229166666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.854166666666667, 0.645833333333333, 0.479166666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.4375, 0.0833333333333333, 0.3125, 0.9375, 
0.583333333333333, 0.645833333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.854166666666667, 
0.5, 0.645833333333333, 0.708333333333333, 0.645833333333333, 
0.791666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.625, 0.479166666666667, 
0.375, 0.4375, 0.645833333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.291666666666667, 
0.583333333333333, 0.8125, 0.625, 0.3125, 0.5, 0.895833333333333, 
0.8125, 0.270833333333333, 0.958333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.729166666666667, 0.75, 0.645833333333333, 0.625, 0.583333333333333, 
0.729166666666667, 0.75, 0.604166666666667, 0.604166666666667, 
0.520833333333333, 0.208333333333333, 0.791666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.6875, 0.291666666666667, 
0.375, 0.625, 0.416666666666667, 0.6875, 0.520833333333333, 0.604166666666667, 
0.729166666666667, 0.8125, 0.541666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.708333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.708333333333333, 0.625, 
0.979166666666667, 0.604166666666667, 0.5, 0.354166666666667, 
0.604166666666667, 0.520833333333333, 0.75, 0.395833333333333, 
0.395833333333333, 0.4375, 0.6875, 0.8125, 0.625, 0.666666666666667, 
0.416666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 0.625, 0.729166666666667, 
0.75, 0.625, 0.395833333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.520833333333333, 
0, 0.770833333333333, 0.5625, 0.583333333333333, 0.708333333333333, 
0.645833333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.458333333333333, 0.625, 
0.645833333333333, 0.604166666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.770833333333333, 
0.354166666666667, 0.6875, 0.75, 0.958333333333333, 0.958333333333333, 
0.520833333333333, 0.708333333333333, 0.708333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.729166666666667, 0.916666666666667, 0.625, 0.541666666666667, 
0.604166666666667, 0.375, 0.479166666666667, 0.729166666666667, 
0.541666666666667, 0.5625, 0.458333333333333, 0.354166666666667, 
0.791666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.104166666666667, 0.645833333333333, 
0.6875, 0.6875, 0.708333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 0.854166666666667, 
0.916666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.708333333333333, 0.375, 
1, 0.416666666666667, 0.375, 0.729166666666667, 0.625, 0.333333333333333, 
0.541666666666667, 0.770833333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.541666666666667, 
0.4375, 0.708333333333333, 0.458333333333333, 0.291666666666667, 
0.416666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.479166666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.729166666666667, 0.604166666666667, 0.645833333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.416666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 0.4375, 0.854166666666667, 
0.5625, 0.708333333333333, 0.4375, 0.791666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.541666666666667, 0.708333333333333, 0.4375, 0.458333333333333, 
0.458333333333333, 0.25, 0.6875, 0.354166666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.145833333333333, 0.770833333333333, 0.625, 0.416666666666667, 
0.479166666666667, 0.479166666666667, 0.104166666666667, 0.458333333333333, 
0.729166666666667, 0.458333333333333, 0.520833333333333, 0.708333333333333, 
0.625, 0.75, 0.5625, 0.5, 0.875, 0.541666666666667, 0.5, 0.625, 
0.583333333333333, 0.645833333333333, 0.479166666666667, 0.541666666666667, 
0.458333333333333, 0.208333333333333, 0.645833333333333, 0.458333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.375, 0.104166666666667, 0.520833333333333, 
0.5, 0.479166666666667, 0.604166666666667, 0.8125, 0.4375, 0.395833333333333, 
0.791666666666667, 0.583333333333333), predictor2 = c(0.423076923076923, 
0.692307692307692, 0.076923076923077, 0.115384615384615, 0.615384615384615, 
0.307692307692308, 0.346153846153846, 0.230769230769231, 0.153846153846154, 
0.615384615384615, 0.730769230769231, 0.307692307692308, 0.884615384615385, 
0.615384615384615, 0.153846153846154, 0.153846153846154, 0, 0.076923076923077, 
0.461538461538462, 0.423076923076923, 0.384615384615385, 0.423076923076923, 
0.346153846153846, 0.346153846153846, 0.423076923076923, 0.153846153846154, 
0.153846153846154, 0.076923076923077, 0.423076923076923, 0.423076923076923, 
0.923076923076923, 0.461538461538462, 0.5, 0.230769230769231, 
0.307692307692308, 0.730769230769231, 0.346153846153846, 0.423076923076923, 
0.384615384615385, 0.461538461538462, 0.230769230769231, 0, 0.692307692307692, 
0.5, 0.461538461538462, 0.653846153846154, 0.423076923076923, 
0.769230769230769, 0.615384615384615, 0.5, 0.653846153846154, 
0.615384615384615, 0.769230769230769, 0.346153846153846, 0.692307692307692, 
0.230769230769231, 0.730769230769231, 0.5, 0, 0.115384615384615, 
0.538461538461538, 0.576923076923077, 0.653846153846154, 0.576923076923077, 
0.692307692307692, 0.615384615384615, 0.423076923076923, 0.461538461538462, 
0.615384615384615, 0.615384615384615, 0.5, 0.538461538461538, 
0.653846153846154, 0, 0.615384615384615, 0.346153846153846, 0.153846153846154, 
0.307692307692308, 0.153846153846154, 0.5, 0.615384615384615, 
0.461538461538462, 0.615384615384615, 0.730769230769231, 0.769230769230769, 
0.423076923076923, 0.576923076923077, 0.653846153846154, 0, 0.307692307692308, 
0.192307692307692, 0.192307692307692, 0.269230769230769, 0.5, 
0.423076923076923, 0.538461538461538, 0, 0.153846153846154, 0.423076923076923, 
0.384615384615385, 0.692307692307692, 0.115384615384615, 0.423076923076923, 
0.5, 0.576923076923077, 0.692307692307692, 0.423076923076923, 
0.5, 0.576923076923077, 0.115384615384615, 0.076923076923077, 
0.192307692307692, 0.269230769230769, 0.846153846153846, 0.192307692307692, 
0.230769230769231, 0.230769230769231, 0.0384615384615385, 0.730769230769231, 
0.0384615384615385, 0.192307692307692, 0.115384615384615, 0.307692307692308, 
0.153846153846154, 0.538461538461538, 0.730769230769231, 0.423076923076923, 
0.461538461538462, 0.346153846153846, 0.923076923076923, 0.692307692307692, 
0.615384615384615, 0.461538461538462, 0.538461538461538, 0.230769230769231, 
0.576923076923077, 0.576923076923077, 0.615384615384615, 0.538461538461538, 
0.653846153846154, 0, 0.307692307692308, 0.769230769230769, 0.076923076923077, 
0.538461538461538, 0.346153846153846, 0, 0.692307692307692, 0.692307692307692, 
0.115384615384615, 0.423076923076923, 0.692307692307692, 0.423076923076923, 
0.307692307692308, 0.423076923076923, 0.576923076923077, 0.423076923076923, 
0.653846153846154, 0.307692307692308, 0.230769230769231, 0.153846153846154, 
0.5, 0.153846153846154, 0.730769230769231, 0.423076923076923, 
0.615384615384615, 0.769230769230769, 1, 0.846153846153846, 0.423076923076923, 
0.538461538461538, 0.807692307692308, 0.192307692307692, 0.769230769230769, 
0.0384615384615385, 0.769230769230769, 0.5, 0.846153846153846, 
0.384615384615385, 0.5, 0.384615384615385, 0.576923076923077, 
0.653846153846154, 0, 0.538461538461538, 0.653846153846154, 0.115384615384615, 
0.692307692307692, 0.384615384615385, 0.692307692307692, 0.576923076923077, 
0.153846153846154, 0.653846153846154, 0.538461538461538, 0.807692307692308, 
0.769230769230769, 0.461538461538462, 0.538461538461538, 0.461538461538462, 
0.461538461538462, 0.153846153846154, 0.230769230769231, 0.769230769230769, 
0.538461538461538, 0.423076923076923, 0.615384615384615, 0.153846153846154, 
0.576923076923077, 0.846153846153846, 0.846153846153846, 0.653846153846154, 
0.076923076923077, 0.230769230769231, 0.846153846153846, 0.576923076923077, 
0.730769230769231, 0.269230769230769, 0.576923076923077, 0.461538461538462, 
0.423076923076923, 0.807692307692308, 0.5, 0.5, 0.423076923076923, 
0.769230769230769, 0.269230769230769, 0.269230769230769), predictor3 = c(0.5, 
0.583333333333333, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0.333333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.166666666666667, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 
0.583333333333333, 0.5, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.833333333333333, 0.5, 0.166666666666667, 
0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.25, 0.416666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.166666666666667, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 
0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.25, 0.0833333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 
0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.5, 0.25, 0.416666666666667, 
0.75, 0.666666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.25, 0.416666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.25, 0.5, 
0.416666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.25, 0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.25, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.166666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.416666666666667, 
0.416666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 0.416666666666667, 
0.5, 0.75, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.25, 0.583333333333333, 0.5, 
0.583333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.166666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 
1, 0.5, 0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.75, 0.583333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.5, 0.75, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.583333333333333, 
0.25, 0.416666666666667, 0.25, 0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.416666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0.75, 
0.333333333333333, 0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.75, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5), criterion = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0)), variable.labels = structure(character(0), .Names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L, row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
117L, 118L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 
129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 
173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 
195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 
207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 
218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 
229L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Prediction model:**

```
model<-glm(formula = criterion ~ predictor1+predictor2+predictor3, 
              family = binomial, data = df)
model
```

**Confusion matrix:**

```
threshold=0.5
predicted_values<-ifelse(predict(model,type="response")>threshold,1,0)
actual_values<-df$criterion
conf_matrix<-table(predicted_values,actual_values)
conf_matrix
```

**ROC analysis:**

```
library(pROC)

roc <- plot.roc(df$criterion, df$predictor1+df$predictor2+df$predictor3,
                 main="Confidence intervals", percent=TRUE,
                 ci=TRUE, # compute AUC (of AUC by default)
                 print.auc=TRUE) # print the AUC (will contain the CI)

mycoords <- coords(roc, "all", transpose = TRUE)

plot(mycoords["threshold",], mycoords["specificity",], type="l", 
     col="red", xlab="Cutoff", ylab="Performance")
lines(mycoords["threshold",], mycoords["sensitivity",], type="l", 
      col="blue")
legend(100, 0.4, c("Specificity", "Sensitivity"), 
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1)

best.coords <- coords(roc, "best", best.method="youden", 
                      transpose = TRUE)

abline(v=best.coords["threshold"], lty=2, col="grey")
abline(h=best.coords["specificity"], lty=2, col="red")
abline(h=best.coords["sensitivity"], lty=2, col="blue")
```

[image]

```
best.coords
```

**Output:**

```
> threshold specificity sensitivity 
> 1.347756   75.000000   45.695364
```

**Question:**

Is this threshold plausible? To what is this threshold referring / how do I interpret this threshold regarding my 3 predictors?

Answer (score 2):

In the linked answer, the ROC curve is being calculated directly from one of the features (`ndka`), not from a model's probability predictions.  So the thresholds are in the scale of that feature.  You might think of this as corresponding to a linear model with a positive coefficient on that feature: you'd end up with the same ROC curve, just with a transformed set of thresholds.

---

*Update after question edited to include code:*

`R` is not my main language, but it looks like your problem is in:

```
roc <- plot.roc(df$criterion, df$predictor1+df$predictor2+df$predictor3,
                 main="Confidence intervals", percent=TRUE,
                 ci=TRUE, # compute AUC (of AUC by default)
                 print.auc=TRUE) # print the AUC (will contain the CI)
```

That second argument is not being treated as a formula the way it is in the modeling code, it's the literal sum of the three predictors.  You should instead pass your model's probability predictions.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to rescale thresholds from ROC model back to model's probabiliy predictions?

Comment: @Jens you'll need to rescale the features themselves.

Comment: In my case, I have 3 predictors which are normalized between 0 and 1. How do I interpret a threshold of 1.34 in my case?

Comment: @Jens What kind of model?  Do you have any predictions of 1.34?

Comment: @BenReiniger, I added the code because I am unsure about the correct answer to your question! Thanks a lot for your great support. I am looking forward to your feedback! :-)